# How to call ajax on type of datatable searchbox in laravel

Tags: laravel, datatables

How to call ajax on type of datatable search box.
for example: If i enter 'abc' in search box then ajax need to call and filter datatable according to name 'abc'

I don't know how to do this.

I have try this

```
oTable = $('#invoice-table').DataTable();  //table id
        $('.invoice-table_filter input').keyup(function(){
            alert(1);
            oTable.search($(this).val()).draw() ;
        })
```

but I'm not getting any alert on keyup.

Please help.

Comment: Assuming `.invoice-table_filter` is a class name and not an id, try `$('input.invoice-table_filter').keyup(...)`

Comment: no, its not working $('input.invoice-table_filter').keyup(
              alert(1)
            );

Comment: Try this `$('#invoice-table input').keyup(...)`

Comment: @trupti it also not working. actually it is datatable searchbox not custom added searchbox